# CMake Project with Google Test which directories should go into .gitignore or be deleted

Tags: git, cmake, googletest

I'm integrating google test (gtest-1.7.0) into my CMake project and I'm wondering which directories I can safely add to my .gitignore (or delete) delete in order to keep my archive as small as possible.

My assumption is that a bunch of these are build scripts for different build systems which I can delete (xcode/ for example)

```
 README
 Makefile.am
 LICENSE
 CONTRIBUTORS
 configure.ac
 CMakeLists.txt
 CHANGES
 aclocal.m4
 configure*
 Makefile.in
 xcode/
 src/
 scripts/
 samples/
 make/
 include/
 fused-src/
 build-aux/
 test/
 msvc/
 m4/
 codegear/
 cmake/
```

I'm probably going to just try to delete directories and see how it goes.

Comment: You can use `scripts/fuse_gtest_files.py` script (https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Fusing_Google_Test_Source_Files). It will generate two files : one header file and one source file. You can use this two files in your CMake project in `add_library` command.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly *how* you've integrated gtest into your cmake project, but all you **really** need is the following:

```
fused-src/gtest/gtest.h
fused-src/gtest/gtest-all.cc
```

If you want to use the main() method defined by gtest, then you'll also need:

```
fused-src/gtest/gtest-main.cc
```

Everything else in the distribution is optional.